# Modeling approach to showing a parabolic effect is greater than that expected by scale boundaries

Tags: variance, nonlinear, quadratic-form

I have conducted an experiment where raters rate different nations on a DV. Each observation is a different nation. I calculated a mean and SD of the DV for each nation. The data we are working with are the means and SDs obtained from the raters. We hypothesize a quadratic effect (see image), in that nations with high standard deviations (less agreement between raters) will have means which are in the middle of the curve, while groups which have low SDs (High agreement between raters) will have very high or very low means on the DV.

The problem:

Naturally there will be more variation at the middle of the curve, and less variation at the tails due to the ceiling and floor effects of the scale.

My question:

Is there a modeling approach to showing the variance of a variable is different from that expected of the scales boundaries?

In the absence of a modeling approach I have fallen back on a simulation, but would prefer a modeling approach if one exists.

[image: Parabolic curve of observed data vs simulation]

Comment: Do you have access to the whole distribution (from which you estimated the mean and SD)?

Comment: Yes, I have the raw information.

Comment: Then it may be better to compare the two distributions rather than just the mean and SD, using for ex. Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

Comment: I hypothesized the form of this curve, not a comparison to the other curve. I am simulating data to form the blue curve, as a crude way of showing the variation in my data is greater than that of expected due to scale boundaries. I would prefer to do this with a modeling approach instead of using the simulation curve.